# ThreeJS updating an FBX Object's attributes after async load

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx

I'm loading an FBX Object into the scene

```
const loader = new FBXLoader();
        loader.load( '{{asset('models/model.fbx')}}', function ( logo ) {
            scene.add( logo );
            logo.position.y = 0;
            logo.position.x = 0;
            logo.position.z = 0;
            logo.updateMatrix();
        });
```

Since "logo" is an async loaded FBX object, I cannot access its properties outside the loader function.

How do I achieve to make its attributes like position, rotation and so on, accessable outside the loader?

I already tried to put anything (including the animate() function) into the loader - but this seems to be not the "clean" way...

Answer (score 3):

Consider to utilize the async/await pattern in your app which makes the code easier to understand. And cleaner.

```js
const loader = new FBXLoader();
const logo = await loader.loadAsync( '{{asset('models/model.fbx')}}' );
scene.add( logo );
```

Notice the usage of [loadAsync()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync) which is available for all loaders. You most likely have to refactor your code so the new `await` does not break your app. You can avoid this by making the surrounding method/function `async`.